# How to use FLICKR API on xcode to show an image of the current position?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, flickr

My question is simple: how can i use FLICKR api to show on the screen of my iphone/ipad an image of the place in the courrent position or, in alternative, an image of a choosed place?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not done an app related to this before. but you might want to try:

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation.html

and a library like this:

https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr